# Sagepay 3121 : The DeliveryFirstnames value is too long

Tags: opayo

I've been trying to resolve this issue the entire day now (wasted my time).
I also got a technician from sagepay involved but they simply take to long to get this done.

When I submit the following information I get 3121 : The DeliveryFirstnames value is too long

```
VendorTxCode=fake
&Amount=320
&Currency=GBP
&Description=Ticket
&SuccessURL=obscured
&FailureURL=obscured
&VendorEmail=obscured.com
&CustomerName=John Deer
&CustomerEMail=obscured.com
&BillingSurname=aaqib
&BillingFirstnames=Abc
&BillingAddress1=abc
&BillingCity=London
&BillingPostCode=se1234
&BillingCountry=GB
&DeliverySurname=Deer
&DeliveryFirstnames=John        
&DeliverAddress1=Bleh
&DeliveryCity=TEST
&DeliveryPostCode=1234
&DeliveryCountry=GB
&AllowGiftAid=0
```

I've tried various combinations in this field and none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear you have encountered difficulties resolving your issue today.  Can you please post a test transaction to our showpost address so I can investigate this for you.  The address is https://test.sagepay.com/showpost/showpost.asp.

If you can then let Sage Pay know the time you tried this transaction we can locate it.

A DeliveryFirstnames value cannot be more than 20 characters. Same for DeliverySurname, BillingFirstnames and BillingSurname. If the value is more than 20 characters, you will get that error.

Thanks,

Sage Pay Support

Comment: Thanks, one of the support team helped me and we resolved the issue finally. It would seem that the encryption function I got broke the post values and drop the "&" after 'DeliveryFirstnames', thus making all the fields after it part of the string.

I just used a new encryption class and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a big struggle I changed my encryption functions and the issue got resolved.
Here is the functions I currently use to successfully make payments.

```
function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function encryptFieldData($input)
{
    $key = 'your password here';
    $iv = $key;

    $input = pkcs5_pad($input, 16);
    $strCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);
    return "@".bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
}
cryptString = 'All your encryption data seperated by an &';
$cryptedData = encryptFieldData($cryptString);
```